# Save only changed objects on server : Restful service + angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I display a list of posts on my page with a like button that the user can toggle on or off.
In order to throttle the traffic with my server, I would like to:

- send updates for **all** the posts where the like status has changed at **once** in the same request
- send updates for the modified posts **only**
- update the like status each N seconds, and on page exit only. Not each time a user toggles a like button.

Is this possible with angularjs?

Comment: When you say "update the like status every N seconds" are you doing that to get new information from the server (in case someone else liked a status), or is it to simply push the clients changes to the server?

Comment: @Trevor Senior I only need to push data back to the server in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've written up an example that can be seen here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/imMGTJ75mKJZT7ispD9E?p=preview

I've spent some time on it with commenting, and providing useful information that gets displayed on the page itself when it runs. Change around the delays if you'd like it to run slower if the messages are moving too quickly.

From your question it looks like you want to save when a user makes any changes to a particular post. You proposed checking every x seconds for changes, but this isn't ideal (though it would be simple to implement with a `setInterval`). You also mentioned saving the changes on page exit, but it's impossible to guarantee that something happens on page exit (a user loosing power for example).

To avoid the above, I would fire the ajax call when the user clicks the "like" button, but throttle them after the first click & store their changes while the throttle timer is running and push all their changes at once after the timer ends.

Here is what my plunker code does in a nutshell:

1. User "likes" or "unlikes" a post and it will make an Ajax call to the server with the new information on the post. At this point, any new "likes" / "unlikes" gets thrown into a "queue" of posts that need to get updated.
2. When the first Ajax call is successful, the throttle timer starts. In the example I've provided it is 5 seconds. Any changes to a post ("likes", "unlikes") will be thrown in that same "queue".
3. After 5 seconds is up, it will check the "queue". If it's empty, no action is taken. If it has items in it (e.g. posts that have changed), then it will make a second ajax call and update the posts on the server.

My example won't mirror what you're working on exactly, but it's the concept that matters. You could modify the code so it doesn't throttle for such a long time, or have it only throttle after x number of ajax calls in a certain amount of time, etc.

Comment: thank you for writing the example! Very helpful. I am having a closer look at it.